# Trying to convert letters into numbers

Tags: php, function, str-replace

So I've created a function to allow letters single letters to be changed in to a 2 digit number.

This is the code:

```
<?php
function Letter2number($abc) {
    //A = 00
    str_replace('a','00',$abc);
    str_replace('A','00',$abc);
    //B = 01
    str_replace('b','01',$abc);
    str_replace('B','01',$abc);
    //C = 02
    str_replace('c','02',$abc);
    str_replace('C','02',$abc);
    //D = 03
    str_replace('d','03',$abc);
    str_replace('D','03',$abc);
    //E = 04
    str_replace('e','04',$abc);
    str_replace('E','04',$abc);
    //F = 05
    str_replace('f','05',$abc);
    str_replace('F','05',$abc);

}
```

?>

When the variable from a form input is processed though this function it was meant to output a 2 digit number.

But the output is blank.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'd like to see more of the code to tell you where it went wrong, anyway i think ord( $character) is doing what your fonction does already

Comment: I see you have resolved your issue, If you use a strtolower or upper in PHP you should only need to do a match on one letter instead of having two, one for lower and one for upper. Unless you really need to return a Upper or Lowercase letter

Answer (score 0):

First attempt at programming? I hope you have a bit of fun. There are two major problems with your code, both have to do with return values.

1. Something like `str_replace('F','05',$abc);` returns a string, which you have to do something with. For instance: `$abc = str_replace('F','05',$abc);`.
2. Your `function` doesn't return anything. At the bottom of the function use `return $abc;`.

Also consider your choice of variable name: `$abc` implies that it contains the alfabet, not one letter. A better name would be `$letter`.

TIP: I used `$abc` in the above points to not confuse you any further, but the code itself is far from optimal. Can you make it better?

Comment: thanks, completely missed the return.
I know some basic stuff, and learning from php.net and w3c.